# Localizing NTFS Folder Share Names

Tags: windows, network-share, ntfs

We have an office in the US and Poland.  This is a long shot but does anyone know if you can specify both an english folder name as well as a polish folder name for the same folder name so that if a polish user looks at the shares they see the polish description but an english speaking user sees the english description?

Figured I might as well ask!

Brent

Comment: Isn't that dependent on the localization of the client OS?

Comment: It would need to be but our Polish speakers have and run the Polish language pack and our US users have the default English language pack in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use multiple shares and mklink to give the same file 2 two paths.  With a lot of files you could script this link creation/naming process. One set with english names and one polish.  There would be no detection as such other than that they would choose the share in their own language.

Comment: Right but for thousands of folders, even scripted would take a lot of effort.  I was curious if something in Windows supported this but I knew it was a longshot.  Almost think this would be a cool feature to boast.

Comment: How would it know what to call them? Names often don't directly translate.  If its not possible to put some sort of structure into a script then how is it going to be any easier for someone else to program?

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way to take advantage of whatever code in Windows does the translation on system folders and applications.  I was thinking along the lines of how ASP.NET Resources worked where there is some resource type file the OS knows about and then utilizes that to translate anything in the shell.  At this point I am pretty sure it's not possible to accomplish in the current environment.

Comment: Even if you could use the built in localisation features, you would still need to set what names it used.  It is not a translation service, the alternates are all predefined.

Comment: Yea, so it looks like this is a dead end.  I'm surprised this isn't possible in Explorer.  Might have to open a connect case for the next version of Windows.